# Laravel api return data format

Tags: laravel, api

In case of building an api with Laravel do we need to return a json like this on each request :

```
$datas = User::find($id)->get();
return response()->json($datas);
```

Or just return the collection like this is enough ?

```
return $datas;
```

What is the cleanest way ?
Thanks !

Comment: Collection is enough. Use response() if you want to return custom HTTP status code (e.g. 404).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to create resource:

`php artisan make:resource UserResource`

Within resource you define fields to return, so everything is over control. You can also pass additional meta data for pagination etc.

```php
$datas = User::find($id)->get();
return UserResource::collection($datas);
```

Returned users is wrapped with `data` key:

```json
{
  "data": [ users array here ]
}
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources for the full docs on it.

Answer (score 1):

Cleanest way of doing it to return the data with response:

```
return response()->json($data,200);
```

If you have multiple variables then you can do it as following:

```
$users = User::find($id)->get();
$admins = Admin::find($id)->get();
$data=['users'=> $users, 'admins'=>$admins];
return response()->json($data,200);
```